# Legend issue in ggplot2

Tags: r

Does anybody know how to remove the dots that R places in variable names (where spaces used exist) when they are read in from .csv files.

I'd like to rename them so that the resulting legend from a ggplot calls the colour something like Variable Name instead of Variable.Name.

I'm just using a simple:

```
  mydata<- read.csv("./user/data.csv", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: Study `help("read.table")`. Alternatively use `gsub` to substitute dots with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `check.names` argument when you read in your data:

```
> read.csv(text ="a a a,b b b,c c c
1,2,3
4,5,6", header = TRUE)
  a.a.a b.b.b c.c.c
1     1     2     3
2     4     5     6
> 
> read.csv(text ="a a a,b b b,c c c
1,2,3
4,5,6", header = TRUE, check.names=FALSE)
  a a a b b b c c c
1     1     2     3
2     4     5     6
```

Or, as @Roland suggests in his comment, you can modify the names after you load your data using `gsub`. Assuming `d` is the first dataframe above:

```
> names(d) <- gsub(".", " ", names(d), fixed=TRUE)
> names(d)
[1] "a a a" "b b b" "c c c"
```

Note that you have to use `fixed=TRUE` otherwise `"."` is interpreted as a regular expression, which happens to mean any character rather than period/dot.

But since these variable names are no longer valid R variable names, you'll need to take a bit of care in referring to them later by using appropriate quotation marks. Some examples, all of which are equivalent:

```
qplot(d[,"a a a"], d[,"b b b"])
qplot(d$"a a a", d$"b b b")
qplot(d$`a a a`, d$`b b b`)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. check.names was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @sb642 If you found this answer helpful, please consider up-voting it and accepting it as correct by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I've just joined the site and do not have the requisite 15 reputation. As soon as I do I will come back and upvote!